# NextJs - Additional keys were returned from getStaticPaths

Tags: javascript, path, next.js

I'm working on a client's project with NextJs,
On the blog section we have different paths, `blog/[:category]`, `blog/[:category]/[:post]` and `blog/author/[:author]` And to get this done I'm using `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`.

I first fetch all the posts and authors from ContentfulAPI and then loop into them to create a valid path to pass it into the paths array

***Ps: It works when I hard code every path individually..***

thats my function:

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

  const posts = await DataController.getEntriesByContentType(
    "componentBlog",
  );

  const blogPosts = posts.items.map(item => {
    return {params: {blog_post: [item.fields.category.replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/'/g, '').toLowerCase(), item.fields.slug]}}
  })

  const authors = await DataController.getEntriesByContentType(
    "author",
  );

  const authorPaths = authors.items.map(item => {
    return {params: {blog_post: ['author', item.fields.slug]}}
  })

  return {
    
    paths: [
      blogPosts,
      authorPaths,
    ],
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

And i get this error when I try to access a blog link :

```
error - Error: Additional keys were returned from `getStaticPaths` in page "/blog/[...blog_post]". URL Parameters intended for this dynamic route must be nested under the `params` key, i.e.:

        return { params: { blog_post: ... } }

Keys that need to be moved: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.

    at C:\Workspace\phoenix-v2\next\new-phoenix\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:518:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.buildStaticPaths (C:\Workspace\phoenix-v2\next\new-phoenix\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:492:17)    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  type: 'Error',
  page: '/blog/[...blog_post]'
}
```

I'm not sure why I run into this error..
thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently passing an array with the params, use the spread operator (`...`) to reduce it. [`Docs`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-paths-key-required)

```
return {
  paths: [...blogPosts, ...authorPaths],
  ...
};
```

Comment: Oh I didn't pay attention to that, thank you